# Thunderbird - Office 365 Exchange - Works Once

Tags: thunderbird, ms-exchange

My workplace uses office 365 with the corresponding exchange setup. I can configure thunderbird to integrate with exchange by using the following settings:

[image]

This will work once, but as soon as thunderbird is closed and reopened, it will fail to connect to the account, and I will get the following error message.

[image]

Is this a Thunderbird issue that I can fix (and if so how?), or a Microsoft issue that I probably can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Thunderbird issue. Thunderbird is very persistent in keeping a password, even it is typed in again. Even if you type it in correctly, it seems to create a kind of initial connection, but for subsequent accesses it uses the stored wrong one again.

For me it helped to go to Preferences -> Security -> Saved Passwords and delete whatever OWA password you find.

Comment: After going to security, I had multiple passwords for the same account. I guess when one deletes the email account and recreates it for when changing a password, it never deletes the original saved password!